# block network access for particular program(browser)

Tags: networking, internet

I have python script that uses pywebkitgtk for fetching web-pages, and I need to block network access for it sometimes. Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are the system administrator, you can use `iptables` (as root) to block certain commands from accessing certain ports, or (at your option) *all* ports (which is equivalent to it being totally unable to access the network).

A good reference is [here](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/120/Application_level_firewalling) but the salient point is:

> If your kernel was compiled with CONFIG_IP_NF_MATCH_OWNER then you can configure your iptables firewall to allow or reject packets on a per-command basis.
>
> The following example shows how to drop all outgoing packets from the acroread command:

`iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --cmd-owner acroread -j DROP`

> The owner module allows several different options to be used to match, allowing either matching against a process ID, a user ID, or a command name.
>
> --uid-owner userid
>   Matches if the packet was created by a process with the given effective user id
>
> --gid-owner userid
>   Matches if the packet was created by a process with the given effective group id
>
> --pid-id processid
>   Matches if the packet was created by a process with the given process id
>
> --cmd-owner name
>   Matches if the packet was created by a process with the given command name.
>
> The "owner" module only allows matches on the OUTPUT chain, which lowers its usefulness a little - but if you're in a standard NAT situation it should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I hope it will help, I need to recompile my kernel to check it... There are one thing I dont sure - would `iptables`-magic work without restarting my program's process?

Comment: o_O 3.2.28 have no such key...

Comment: I believe if you have this enabled, it will take effect on running processes without restarting them.

Comment: look at this - http://superuser.com/questions/465235/in-which-kernel-version-config-ip-nf-match-owner-appears/465289#465289 - this key exist only in old kernels (2.6.0 - 2.6.24)...

Comment: It was probably wrapped into another key or enabled by default. Are you able to get the above functionality to work with `iptables` with your existing kernel?

Comment: of course I checked it - I unable - `iptables v1.4.12: unknown option "--cmd-owner"`

Comment: The `--cmd-owner` option was removed in the 2.6.14 ver. of the Kernel. http://www.network-builders.com/iptables-kernel-owner-module-t103044.html. Also see here: http://serverfault.com/questions/344756/linux-restricting-outgoing-on-an-application-basis