# in which kernel version CONFIG_IP_NF_MATCH_OWNER appears?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel

In which kernel version CONFIG_IP_NF_MATCH_OWNER key appears? I dont see it while `make mennuconfig` on 3.2.28 that I am trying to compile for my ubuntu 12.04 (3.2.0 - default kernel version).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to 
[LKDDB](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/IP_NF_MATCH_OWNER.html)

2.6.0 - 2.6.24